# How to move sx= inside styles.scss?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Would you help me in How to move `sx={{}}` to styles.scss in React.
I have ErrorState and it appears in the middle of the page. However, i want to have styling in a separate file but once I moved, the styling is no longer works.

```
const ErrorState=({width})=>{
  const{t}=useTranslation();
return(
  <>
   <divdata-testid="payment-cards-container-id"/>
<Box
    data-testid="errorState"
    width={width}
    sx={{
         display:'grid',
         placeItems:'center',
         minheight:'100vh'
       }}
 >
    <Box>
        <ErrorIcon/>
        <Typography
              variant="body-copy-medium"
              style={{marginTop:20}}
        >
    </Typography>
    <Button
          data-testid="refreshButton"
          style={{marginTop:20,width:'fit-content'}}
          onClick={()=>window.location.reload()}
    </Button>
    </Box>
    </Box>
    </>
   );
};
```

I move `sx = {{}}` to styles.scss

Inside styles.scss:
I have

```
. Error-state {

    .Error-state{
             display: grid;
             Place-items: center;
             Min-heights: 100vh;}
```

Then I have `className=“Error-state`
Inside the `<Box>` but the ErrorState no longer appear in the middle of the page like when I have `sx=` directly in the file.

Comment: The css doesn't look valid. Letter-casing _matters_, e.g. `Place-items` should be `place-items` and `min-heights` doesn't exist. You may have meant `min-height`.

Comment: Thank you, it was my typo and once it fixed, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the index.scss file from its right location into the component like this

```
import './styles.scss';
```

After that add the classname `.Error-state` in Box component like this

```
<Box data-testid="errorState" width={width} className="Error-state">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...
**Here minimizing the code**..(Your can add up yours here);
Create first scss file...

style.scss file

```
.Error-state {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then compile it usnig a scss compiler

(Assuming your compiled css file is on the same directory)

```
import './temp.css'

function App() {
  const ErrorState = ({ width }) => {
  //const { t } = useTranslation();
  }
  return (
    <>
          <div data-testid="payment-cards-container-id" />
          <div
            data-testid="errorState"
            style={{
              display: 'grid',
              placeItems: 'center',
              minheight: '100vh'
            }}
            className="Error-state"
          >
            YOUR THINGS
          </ div>
        </>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```